# Amazon Lex changing status from Ready to NOT_BUILD after 2 or 3 mins

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, boto3, amazon-lex

I am trying build a BOT using put_bot boto3 API operation and processbehaviour is set to BUILD. Lex will build the bot but after 2 or 3 mins it changes its status to NOT_BUILD. When i tried to BUILD the same for second time manually or through calling put_bot api again, then it build successfully. This status change happen intermittently. This happens 1 out of 10 times. Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar using the Java Lex Model building SDK and in my case it was a result of the build failing.

Have you looked for errors wtih `put_bot` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no errors in cloudwatch and second time when i build the BOT , it build successfully and none of Build is failing.

Comment: Also i have tried printing response after each event and its giving response 200

Comment: Not sure then. This isn't really scientific, but I would suggest adding in a bit of a delay between the various slot and intent creation calls to cater for any delays with Lex creating the components.

Comment: Added Delay of 1 min between each event but facing same issue. I am checking with AWS team on this.